# How to return the value after volley response Android

Tags: android, return, android-volley, response

I am new to volley in Android. I tried to collect data from database via volley request. However, the program continue proceed before the value come in. Anyone has solutions regard this issue? I have used break point to check the sequence of the program. It will run return categoryList in DatabaseCategory before the onSuccess function been called.

This is the class to call DatabaseCategory

```
public class DatabaseFacade implements Database {

private DatabaseCategory databaseCategory;

public DatabaseFacade(Context context) {
    databaseCategory = new DatabaseCategory(context);
}

@Override
public List<Category> readCategory() {
    return (List<Category>) databaseCategory.loadData(DatabaseUrl.getCategoryReadUrl(), null);
}
```

}

This is the class to load the data

```
public class DatabaseCategory extends DatabaseAbstract{

private Context context;
private List<?> categoryList;

public DatabaseCategory(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public List<?> loadData(String url, Object object) {
    databaseLoad = new DatabaseLoad(context, ObjectType.CATEGORY, url);
    databaseLoad.execute(new CallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<?> list) {
            categoryList = list;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFail(String msg) {
            // Do Stuff
        }
    });
    return categoryList;
}
```

This is the class to process volley request

```
public class DatabaseLoad {

private static final String FAIL_MESSAGE = "Some error occur. Please try later.";
private static final String STATUS_CODE = "success";
private static final int SUCCESS = 1;
private Context context;
private ObjectType objectType;
private String url;
private JSONObject json;
private List<?> loadList;

public DatabaseLoad(Context context, ObjectType type, String url) {
    this.context = context;
    this.objectType = type;
    this.url = url;
}

public void execute(final CallBack onCallBack) {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {

                    JSONObject obj;
                    try {
                        obj = new JSONObject(s);
                        if(obj.getInt(STATUS_CODE)==SUCCESS){
                            Log.d("logindatabase","success");
                            switch (objectType) {
                                case CATEGORY:
                                    loadList = loadCategory(obj);
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                            onCallBack.onSuccess(loadList);
                        }else{
                            Log.d("logindatabase","fail");
                            Toast.makeText(context, FAIL_MESSAGE , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(context, FAIL_MESSAGE , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        onCallBack.onFail(e.toString());
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    //Showing toast
                    Toast.makeText(context, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Creating parameters
            Map<String,String> params;
            //Adding parameters
            switch (objectType) {
                case CATEGORY:
                    params = loadCategoryParameter();
                    break;

                default:
                    params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                    break;
            }

            //returning parameters
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);



}

private Map<String,String> loadCategoryParameter() {
    Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    return params;
}

private List<Category> loadCategory(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
    List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray categoryArray ;
    categoryArray = obj.getJSONArray("posts");

    for (int i = 0; i < categoryArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = categoryArray.getJSONObject(i);
        int id = c.getInt("id");
        String name = c.getString("name");
        String type = c.getString("type");
        String image = c.getString("image");
        Category category = new Category(id,name,type,"",image);
        categoryList.add(category);
    }
    //Log.d("categorylist",obj.toString());
    return categoryList;
}
}
```

Comment: Step #1: Have `loadData()` be of type `void`. Step #2: Have `loadData()` take some sort of callback, that you use to deliver the `List` of results to whoever wants it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have updated my question. I use DatabaseFacade to call DatabaseCategory. The DatabaseFacade's constructor is context. I cannot use context to call the function.

Comment: That does not change the fact that `loadData()` cannot return the `List`. It also does not change the advice from my original comment.